# wifi hardware equipped with device or not

Tags: android, wifi, hardware

I want to check **WiFi** hardware equipped with my device or not.

How I get this information?

I can get WifiManager  instance from below code.

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_WIFI)) {
     // WiFi  
 }
```

see [PackageManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html)

Comment: Can you provide a link out to relevant documentation? Naked answers have a tendency to get deleted because they're contextually hard to process.